# performSegueWithIdentifier failing presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window

Tags: ipad, ios5, storyboard

I have a Master/Detail view which opens a popover view via storyboard segue.  There is an add button on the navigation bar of the Master view controller which works fine.

I added an editing mode where the same popover is invoked by selecting a table cell in edit mode.  It fails from the [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addQuery" sender:self]; statement.  The viewDidLoad in the popover is invoked, but after that the exception is thrown.

I am not invoking presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem - it seems to be coming from the performSegueWithIdentifier.

There is no question that the Master View Controller has a window - a table cell for that view was clicked to start the whole process that is failing.

The popover is the beginning of a navigation controller sequence, which may be part of the problem.  Everything is working fine when it really is invoked by the button, just trying to programmatically invoke it is failing.

I have tried changing the "sender" for the performSegueWithIdentifier to no avail.

I suspect the problem has to do with the segue not being invoked by a button, and I do not know how to fake that out.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377001/popovers-cannot-be-presented-from-a-view-which-does-not-have-a-window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appear to be some bugs in how ipad popover segue's work - see [Wayne Hartman's blog post](http://blog.waynehartman.com/archive/2012/01/07/uistoryboard-on-ios-5-the-good-the-bad-and-the.aspx)

A simple test revealed that viewWillAppear is being called after viewDidLoad.

I think I understand the problem... havent' worked out the solution yet.

The order in which the methods were called are...

1. [initiate segue]
2. viewDidLoad
3. prepareForSegue
4. viewWillAppear

I moved my initialization code to the viewWillAppear method - and it worked.

In general, I feel it may be a good idea to initialize within viewWillAppear instead of viewDidLoad anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue:

I am using UIDocumentInteractionController to open a kaynote document in Kaynote app. I was using same code:

```
[docController presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem:_actionBarButtonItem animated:YES];
```

Code above was opening popover from actiobBarButtonItem with options what app I would like to use to open my file. If I same thing from DetailViewController I get same error message as author of this thread: "Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window"

**And I was able to find a quick solution for my issue** . I am not sure if it will be relevant to yours. Instead of using "presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem" I used "presentOpenInMenuFromRect" and thats it. You just need to define right place for popover to apear