# UIPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect crashes

Tags: iphone, ios, uipopover

I'm trying to create a simple popover somewhere on the screen, but for some reason it just keeps crashing.
It doesn't give me any erro (Zombie Objects are enabled)

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
viewController.view = view;

UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:viewController];
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100) inView:self.view.superview permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
```

I'm just trying to create a popover at a random position, is this not possible?

EDIT:
Also tried it like this

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *popover;

@synthesize popover = _popover;

UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
viewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

_popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:viewController];
_popover.delegate = self;
[_popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
```

EDIT2: It might be relevant and I forgot to mention is, but this code is being called in another view.

This works fine!

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
viewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(200, 200);
viewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

UIPopoverController *popver1 = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:viewController];
[popver1 presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(250, 200, 200, 200) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

DocumentViewController *document = [[DocumentViewController alloc] initWithIssue:_readerModel.currentIssue];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:document animated:YES];
```

When I call the same EXACT code inside DocumentViewController it doesn't work.

Comment: Your viewcontroller already have a view - why are you affecting a view to its view property? This doesn't sound right.

Comment: @tiguero Sure, but that's not the problem here right now, I just made this as an example to show the code.

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm. Can't see no reason for a crash here (code works fine when I test it).

**But**: If `self.view.superview` from your code is `nil` it will crash with a message like

```
 [...] Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window [...]
```

**And**: There are also some more fixes to do if you want to present the `popover` properly:

- Set `contentSizeForViewInPopover` property in your `viewController`
  to manage the real size of your `popover`.
- Change `UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown` to `UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny` 
  (especially when you use a rect with `origin=(0,0)` to present from).
  Otherwise you won't see the `popover`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but unfortunately it doesn't help me any further, i changed `self.view.superview` back to `self.view` since it was `nil`. Added the `contetnSizeForViewInPopover` and change the arrow direction to any, but still it just crashes without any warning when i call `presentPopoverFromRect`

Comment: So there is no message in your Xcode console about the crash? Do you test on a real device? If so: Did you check device logs?

Comment: No message whatsoever, just `Thread 1: signal SIGTRAP`, I don't have a real device at hand atm.

Comment: Googling for SIGTRAP tells me that it could be all about Xcode/Debugger and has nothing to do with your code. 1st thing I'd try: restart Xcode.

Comment: I tried restarting before after I google SIGTRAP, but that doesn't seem to help much, maybe just restarting my entire computer.

Answer (score 2):

you can check if the window is nil before presenting popover by

`if (self.view.window != nil)`

also are you calling the above code in `viewDidLoad` OR `viewWillAppear`?

Can you try the same code from `viewDidAppear` method or `didMoveToWindow` method

Comment: `self.view.window` is indeed `nil`, `viewDidAppear` doesn't seem to be called.

Comment: may be you are calling this code from a class which added as a subview, so viewDidAppear method will not get called in subview class. Can you call the method which contains popover related code from viewDidAppear of superview class. Also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377001/popovers-cannot-be-presented-from-a-view-which-does-not-have-a-window) similar question.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should define  popover as a property, not a local variable